# Cannot change Tab Settings in System Admin Profile because another permission setting is blocking save

Tags: profile, developer-org, system-admin, tab-settings

In my develop org, I want to change `Active Scratch Orgs` so it's `Tab Settings` are `Default On`

But when I press **Save** I get this error:

> Permission Subscribe to Dashboards: Add Recipients depends on
>   permission(s): Subscribe to Dashboards

[image]

But I am unable to edit the `Subscribe to Dashboards` setting on the standard `System Administrator` profile.

[image]

And because I am using a Developer org, I am unable to create a support case with Salesforce.

This is blocking my ability to see the `Active Scratch Orgs` tab because it's current value is `Default Off`

What can I do to fix this?

---

This would be quickly fixed if I could log a support case, please vote for this idea:

- [Salesforce Idea: Ability to log a case using Developer Org for Support](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lGplQAE)

Comment: Got same issue, logged case with Salesforce, they fixed it to me. Can you try to create permission set with given tab settings and assign it to yourself?

Comment: As stated in the question, I cannot create a support case because it's a developer org. Tried create a permission set, but you cannot change the `Tab Settings` using permission sets. Which means I cannot see the tab

Comment: Another workaround be creating of clone of system admin profile with mentioned checkboxes ticket on

Comment: I asked about this on Partner Community. I was advised that the only way for non-Partners without support cases to escalate this is to post on Success Community. I responded asking if it should be to any particular group or person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your System Administrator profile looks like it's broken. Unfortunately, there's no way to fix it. Instead:

- *Clone* the System Administrator profile
- *Edit* in the new permissions that you need
- *Create* a new temporary user with that new profile
- *Log In* as the new user
- *Assign* the new profile to your user
- *Log In* as yourself again
- *Deactivate* the temporary new user

This will allow you to make future changes to your profile as necessary. Do remember not to accidentally remove administrative permissions from this profile or you might end up losing administrative access your your developer org.

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to chime in that I have checked two of my dev orgs on NA96 (previously NA35) and I see the same breakage of the Admin profile. I also see it on my pre-release GS0 org.

I do not see the same breakage in other Production and Dev orgs (including NA40, NA54). Those orgs do not even have the "Subscribe To Dashboards: Add Recipients" option.

So this is a systematic problem affecting the default Admin profile of a number of specific instances. I will report it to the Partner Community.

EDIT: This is a Known Issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AU7mQAG

Since you cannot create a support case as they suggest, maybe there is a way to escalate this on Trailblazer Community?